# Mono with Owin Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, mono, asp.net-identity, owin

I have an Owin application I'm running in Mono, and I'm trying to get authentication to work properly on it. I used the info on [this page](https://coding.abel.nu/2014/06/writing-an-owin-authentication-middleware/) as a start. I quickly realized that Owin Authentication uses some Windows specific libraries. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945150/usercookieauthentication-in-mono-3-4-1) had a workaround for that, though, which I thought would be enough. It wasn't.

The following code throws the exception described in the other question (in another place than the question describes (see comment in code)). If I try to comment out stuff to locate the error exceptions about Owin pipeline are being thrown (because of dependencies). If I comment out enough to remove that the first exception appears again.

Has anybody successfully been able to set up authentication in Owin (using AspNet Identity) in Mono?

**Startup**

```
public void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Add the AspNet Identity user manager to the Owin context
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

    // This was the first line to fail, but adding the AesDataProtectorProvider as
    // described in the referred question fixed that
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        },
        TicketDataFormat = new SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>(
            DataSerializers.Ticket,
            new AesDataProtectorProvider("myAuthKey"),
            TextEncodings.Base64)
    });

    // This causes an exception complaining that the Windows only assembly
    // DpapiDataProtector can't be loaded, as described in the referred question
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    // Set up the custom middleware as described in the first link
    // Something inside this causes other exceptions.
    app.Use(typeof(AuthMiddleware), app, new AuthOptions());
}
```

**AuthMiddleware**

```
public class AuthMiddleware : AuthenticationMiddleware<AuthOptions>
{
    public AuthMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, IAppBuilder app, AuthOptions options)
        : base(next, options)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Options.SignInAsAuthenticationType))
        {
            options.SignInAsAuthenticationType = app.GetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType();
        }
        if (options.StateDataFormat == null)
        {
            var dataProtector = app.CreateDataProtector(typeof(AuthMiddleware).FullName,
            options.AuthenticationType);
            options.StateDataFormat = new PropertiesDataFormat(dataProtector);
        }
    }

    protected override AuthenticationHandler<AuthOptions> CreateHandler()
    {
        return new AuthHandler();
    }
}
```

**AuthOptions**

```
public class AuthOptions : AuthenticationOptions
{
    public AuthOptions()
        : base("MyApp")
    {
        Description.Caption = "MyApp";
        // Where to redirect requests if not authenticated
        CallbackPath = new PathString("/login");            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive;
    }

    public PathString CallbackPath { get; set; }
    public string SignInAsAuthenticationType { get; set; }
    public ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationProperties> StateDataFormat { get; set; }
}
```

**AuthHandler**

```
public class AuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthOptions>
{
    protected override Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Options.SignInAsAuthenticationType);
        var properties = Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(Request.Query["state"]);
        return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties));
    }

    protected override Task ApplyResponseChallengeAsync()
    {
        if (Response.StatusCode == 401)
        {
            var challenge = Helper.LookupChallenge(Options.AuthenticationType, Options.AuthenticationMode);
            if (challenge != null)
            {
                var state = challenge.Properties;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.RedirectUri))
                {
                    state.RedirectUri = Request.Uri.ToString();
                }
                var stateString = Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(state);
                Response.Redirect(WebUtilities.AddQueryString(Options.CallbackPath.Value, "state", stateString));
            }
        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override async Task<bool> InvokeAsync()
    {
        Request.Environment.Add("Context", Context);

        // If user is not logged in and tries to access any page that is not in
        // the list of allowed pages, redirect to login page
        if (Context.Authentication.User == null && 
            !Request.Path.ToString().StartsWith("/login"))
        {
            Response.Redirect(Options.CallbackPath.Value);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the code submitted above includes more than is necessary to get Owin authentication to work (and which doesn't work with Mono). Having researched and tried a lot of permutations I do believe I have authentication in a working condition now. I don't know if it necessarilly is the *correct* condition, but as long as it works...

Using the following setup only the pages in the list of allowed pages (Controlled by the method `public override async Task<bool> InvokeAsync()` in `AuthHandler`) are accessible to users who are not logged in.
On a login page I can use the `ApplicationUserManager` to sign in a user. After the signin all pages hosted by Owin are accessible.

**Startup**

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    },
    TicketDataFormat = new SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>(
        DataSerializers.Ticket,
        new AesDataProtectorProvider("myAuthKey"),
        TextEncodings.Base64)
});

app.Use(typeof(AuthMiddleware), app, new AuthOptions());
```

**AuthMiddleware**

```
public class AuthMiddleware : AuthenticationMiddleware<AuthOptions>
{
    public AuthMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, IAppBuilder app, AuthOptions options)
        : base(next, options)
    {
        if (options.StateDataFormat == null)
        {
            options.StateDataFormat = new PropertiesDataFormat(new AesDataProtectorProvider("myAuthKey"));
        }
    }

    protected override AuthenticationHandler<AuthOptions> CreateHandler()
    {
        return new AuthHandler();
    }
}
```

**AuthHandler**

```
public class AuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthOptions>
{
    protected override Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {
        // This method never gets called in the current setup,
        // but it is required because the compilation fails otherwise.
        // Therefore only return an empty object.
        return Task.FromResult<AuthenticationTicket>(null);
    }

    protected override Task ApplyResponseChallengeAsync()
    {
        if (Response.StatusCode == 401)
        {
            var challenge = Helper.LookupChallenge(Options.AuthenticationType, Options.AuthenticationMode);
            if (challenge != null)
            {
                var state = challenge.Properties;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.RedirectUri))
                {
                    state.RedirectUri = Request.Uri.ToString();
                }
                var stateString = Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(state);
                Response.Redirect(WebUtilities.AddQueryString(Options.CallbackPath.Value, "state", stateString));
            }
        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override async Task<bool> InvokeAsync()
    {
        // If user is not logged in and tries to access any page that is not in
        // the list of allowed pages, redirect to login page.
        // Add any additional pages not protected by authentication here
        if (Context.Authentication.User == null && 
            !Request.Path.ToString().StartsWith("/login"))
        {
            Response.Redirect(Options.CallbackPath.Value);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GitHub repository to showcase Mono WebAPI, OAuth2 Bearer token authentication, **AspNet.Identity + MySQL UserStore**:

> https://github.com/shturm/mono-webapi

[image]
[image]

Few things to get clear:

1. **AspNet.Identity** is a set of interfaces (*Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core*) and their implementations (*Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/Owin*) that roughly describe *repository pattern for persisting **accounts** in a database*.
2. **AspNet.Identity** does not do authentication/authorization. It creates, saves, updates, deletes users while taking care of passwords.
3. **AspNet.Identity** main classes used are *UserManager* (from *Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core*) and *SignInManger* (from ***Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin***). *SignInManager* is not necessary to perform any kind of OWIN authentication.
4. The code you posted is strictly **Microsoft.Owin** related and has nothing to do with **AspNet.Identity** except for ***ApplicationUserManager*** which in Visual Studio templates extends *Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager*.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication in Owin use async pipeline, but Mono does not support one.

I make pull request for mono https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/3048.
It makes Synchronous execution of asynchronous web api stack.

Now you may use Owin Authentication with this fix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving an answer related to, but not addressing, the OP's problem as a resource for anyone else out there who haven't made the jump to .NET Core.

On Mono, Mod-Mono and Apache, my experience was that the `regenerateIdentity` function was failing on Mono, but would succeed when run locally from VS.

**Before the fix (startup.auth.cs)**

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
   AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
   LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
   Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
   {  
       OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
           validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
           regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => AuthenticationService.RefreshIdentityAsync(manager, user))
   }
});
```

I noticed in Chrome's Dev Tools (application tab) that the cookie remained, because it
was set to expire an extra 2 weeks into the future.

**My solution was to adjust the 'Expires' time of the cookie such that it aligned with the validation interval**. Now the client is responsible for the cookie eviction, and Mono doesn't have to handle the cookie on regeneration. I realize this is not a generic fix, but for many, I'm certain this is good enough.

**After the fix**

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
   AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
   LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
   ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
   SlidingExpiration = false,
   Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
   {
       OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
           validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
           regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => AuthenticationService.RefreshIdentityAsync(manager, user))
   }
});
```